# Can I disentangle an interaction in a multilevel model by reordering factors?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I have a multilevel model with two factors (factor A - 2 levels; factor B - 3 levels) and continuous covariate, all of which interact. There is a random effect of participant and random slopes on the factors. Using lme4 in R The model looks like this:

```
lmer(DV ~ covariate*FactorA*FactorB + (1 + FactorA + FactorB | participant), data = dat)
```

The three way interaction is significant and I want to disentangle it. I am aware that this can be done using packages like emmeans.

However, I am wondering if a valid alternative would be to simply change the reference categories for the factors and re-run the model to observe the levels where main effects and lower order interactions occur versus where they do not. Additionally, if I did this would I need to apply a correction like you would for traditional post-hoc tests (e.g., Tukey, Bonferroni)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter how you parameterize the model, the fitted values will be exactly the same, so the estimated cell means, and the relationships among them, do not change a bit. So you're going to have to face that 3-way interaction head-on.

That said, what might change your *perception* of the covariate would be to center it or standardize it. Doing so often reduces the correlations among regression coefficients.